# %s expects 'char *', but argument is 'char[100]'

Tags: c, printf

I have something along the lines of:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
char s[100];
} literal;

literal foo()
{
return (literal) {"foo"};
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%s", foo().s);
    return 0;
}
```

And I get this error when compiling it (with gcc):

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘char[100]’ [-Wformat=]

any1 has any ideas on how I can fix it? And what is wrong with that function return type?

**EDIT**
The problem (if not clear in the discussion) was the c standard gcc was using to compile the file. if you use -std=c99 or -std=c11 it works.

Comment: there seems to be tons of error in your code. please explain what you are trying to do with your code

Comment: It's a compilers project where I need to generate some c code. Everything works except using that literal return type there. If you could point out where you see these tons of errors it'd be something.

Comment: What's the meaning of this line ?
'return (literal) {"foo"};'

Comment: (literal){"foo";} just encapsulates the string "foo" in a literal struct, not much more that that. I just return the struct.

Comment: I was able to build it with other compilers as well, but it's for a school project and my professor will use gcc, so I need to make it work there :(

Comment: Are you sure you posted the same code which is giving you the error you listed ? The given code [can't be reproduced](http://ideone.com/UDMkhg).

Comment: Yeah, it was part of a bigger c file so I just created this small example and copy pasted both the code and the error

Comment: You seem to be confused as to what "literal" means.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit Here, "literal" does not represent a word in English, just take it to mean string.

Comment: @PHM: Then say "string" instead of misusing a term.

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit It's just an identifier, you shouldn't botter this much with what name I give an identifier. Furthermore, in the project I was working on, it was important that I used that name for the identifier (again, not an English word). I'm not misusing a term, since it's not an English term.

Comment: @PHMitrious: That's absurd. You're deliberately using a term to mean one thing, when it very specifically means something else in the domain in which you're programming (C++). Why on earth would you do that? _It makes your code nonsensical to the normal reader_ (which is why I'm "bothered" by it or, rather, trying to help you understand that _you_ should be "bothered" by it); if nothing else, you should have renamed `literal` in your code to something else before posting it here, if only people working on your project clearly understand its alternative meaning.

Comment: As I said before, the reason is specific to what I was doing at that time. And the only reason I no point in your complaints is that is doesn't have any impact in understanding the problem I was having there (if it did I would've renamed it). As you can see from the fact that everyone that participated in the discussion understood the problem and just ignored an identifier's name. I think the kind of discussion you started here is, at most, unhelpful/unrelated for the problem that I presented, which is not helpful at all (as you didn't provide any information related to the topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an error but a warning, not all warnings that `-Wall` produces are sensible.

Here the compiler is "kind-of" right: before evaluation your argument is an array and not a pointer, and taking the address of a temporary object is a bit dangerous. I managed to get rid of the warning by using the pointer explicitly

```
printf("%s\n", &foo().s[0]);
```

Also you should notice that you are using a rare animal, namely an object of *temporary lifetime*, the return value or your function. Only since C99, there is a special rule that allows to take the address of such a beast, but this is a corner case of the C language, and you would probably be better off by using some simpler construct. The lifetime of the pointer ends with the end of the expression. So if you would try to assign the pointer to a variable, say, and use it later on in another expression, you would have undefined behavior.

*Edit(s)*: As remarked by mafso in a comment, with C versions from before C99, it was not allowed to take the address of the return value of the function. As Pascal Cuoq notes, the behavior of your code is undefined even for C99, because between the evaluation of the arguments and the actual call of the function there is a sequence point. C11 rectified this by indroducing the *object of temporary lifetime* that I mentioned above.

Comment: I would hesitate to say the compiler is "kind-of right". Per the language, the argument has type `char *` regardless of the fact that the object named by the identifier used in the expression for the argument has type `char[100]`.

Comment: Wow, there are two glorious downvoters around, today. Care to explain your rude behavior. (@R.. I know this isn't you.)

Comment: Actually I'm not even sure if the code as written is valid, but I think in terms of types my comment is still correct.

Comment: @starrify, rude. I didn't say that it is an error, neither did gcc or anybody else.

Comment: @starrify The code as posted by the OP should run but it doesn't. This "workaround" makes the code work and the problem is solved even if you don't know exactly why. There is no reason to downvote.

Comment: @starrify: In this case I'm not sure if it's even valid to use `foo().s` (is the pointer it decays to a valid pointer?) but I think the GCC warning is still wrong.

Comment: @starrify, a compiler is free to give any kind of diagnostics, as long as it compiles the code correctly. And I maintain that your behavior is rude.

Comment: @R.., yes it is correct, there is a special rule to take addresses of objects with temporary lifetime.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Yes, I just found it -- [6.2.4 paragraph 8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p8).

Comment: @starrify and others; I suspect OP compiles as C89, there was something changed regarding array decay. Cf. [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Subscripting.html#Subscripting). I can't find the relevant changes in the specs, though. Clang compiles with different defaults and gives the same warning with `-std=c89 -Wall`. [edit:] And the code crashes when compiled with `clang` and "works" (I suspect UB) when compiled with `gcc` on my machine.

Comment: @mafso Thank you. And sorry to all for any inconvenience.

Comment: I will mark your answer as a reply, it really depends on how the compiler sees it, if I find a safer way to go about it I will post it here, but the discussion in your answer provides enough info for one to understand what's going on.

Comment: @mafso, thanks, that was the missing piece, array to pointer evaluation is only allowed since C99.

Comment: Actually, the code in the question is erroneous for a C99 program. It should only be compiled with a compiler explicitly documented as allowing access to temporary objects after the next sequence point (as some compilers are). A change in the C11 standard makes the program valid with respect to C11. See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP35-C.+Do+not+modify+objects+with+temporary+lifetime for a discussion (scroll down to “This noncompliant code example conforms to the C11 Standard; however, it fails to conform to C99.”).

Comment: @PascalCuoq, thanks, I added that aspect to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly why maybe someone with more knowledge in C than me can explain it but writing `main()` on this way:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    literal b = foo();
    printf("%s", b.s);
    return 0;
}
```

The code prints "foo" correctly on GCC 4.5.4

Comment: Yeah, that might work, but I'm doing some code generation, so creating a new variable for each call of a function is not feasible

Comment: PHMitrious yeah I know, there should be another way you are returning struct by value so it should work perfectly. @starrify I'm solving the OP problem with a working code, It's up to him to accept or not my answer but I don't see why you should downvote it.

Comment: @starrify Ok, you are right sorry. No, `puts("foo")` doesn't work.

Comment: @Andres Sorry but it's now believed that your answer _is correct_ since it makes an undefined behaviour defined with standards before C99. See mafso's comment under the accepted answer. Sorry again for any inconvenience. Also I cannot cancel the downvote now according to rules of SO.